# Wildcard character in S3 fetch files in Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to save files in AWS S3. Another process need to fetch files written in last 1 hour.

I am planning to provide hour in the name itself like, `2017/08/23/07/File_Names`. Can I retrieve all these files using wildcard or something i.e., list all the files with prefix `2017/08/23/07` and then can fetch and use them?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution should work. However, if process runs at `14:30`, does last hour only means get all files saved from `14:00` onwards or does it mean get all files from `13:30` onwards?

You can use `listObjects` command to get all keys in the bucket. Once your process has all the keys, filter the keys and then only get objects against keys which qualify the filtering criteria.